# Sum and multiply text-boxes in laravel framework

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

Currently I'm doing my project using the Laravel framework and I'm just a beginner. I have a problem: when I sum and multiply the text-boxes, my program does not display the result. I wonder if my code is correct. Here is my form code:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <strong>Rate Lecture Per Hour (RM) :</strong>
        {!! Form::text('lecturePerHour', null, array('placeholder' => 'Rate Lecture Per Hour (RM)','class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'lecturePerHour', 'onkeyup' => 'calc()')) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Rate Tutorial Per Hour (RM) :</strong>
        {!! Form::text('tutorialPerHour', null, array('placeholder' => 'Rate Tutorial Per Hour (RM)','class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'tutorialPerHour', 'onkeyup' => 'calc()')) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Total Working Hour per Month (Lecture) :</strong>
        {!! Form::text('lectureWorkTime', null, array('placeholder' => 'Total Working Hour (Lecture)','class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'lectureWorkTime', 'onkeyup' => 'calc()')) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Total Working Hour per Month (Tutorial) :</strong>
        {!! Form::text('tutorialWorkTime', null, array('placeholder' => 'Total Working Hour (Tutorial)','class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'tutorialWorkTime', 'onkeyup' => 'calc()')) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Total Salary Per Month (RM) :</strong>
        {!! Form::text('totalSalary', null, array('placeholder' => 'Total Salary Per Month (RM)','class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'totalSalary')) !!}
    </div>
```

And this is my Javascript code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function calc()
    {
      var value1 = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName('lecturePerHour').value);
      var value2 = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName('tutorialPerHour').value);
      var value3 = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName('lectureWorkTime').value);
      var value4 = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName('tutorialWorkTime').value);

      var result = (value1*value3)+(value2*value4);
      document.getElementsByName('totalSalary').value = result;
    }
    </script>
```

Please help me.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) doesn’t return a single element (like getElementById), but a collection.  The clue is in the name of the method, getElement**s**ByName.

Since you likely want the first or only element with such a name, pull out the zeroth element of that collection, ie:

`var value1 = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName('lecturePerHour')[0].value);`

Comment: I'm sorry for my late responses due to my damaged laptop for a while. I've tried as you suggested but it still can't display the result automatically. Is it correct if I've put the javascript code in the layout/app.blade.php file while the form code in form.blade.php?Thank you for your response.

Comment: It shouldn't matter in which file you have the javascript code that defines the function calc.  The true answer to "is it correct" is about coding style and how the rest of your site is broken down into blade pieces.

Comment: I've figured out the solution,I'm simply remove the parseFloat and its do the trick. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use `document.getElementById()` for a single element rather than `document.getElementsByName()`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calc()
{
  var value1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lecturePerHour').value);
  var value2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('tutorialPerHour').value);
  var value3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lectureWorkTime').value);
  var value4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('tutorialWorkTime').value);

  var result = (value1*value3)+(value2*value4);
  document.getElementById('totalSalary').value = result;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry for my late responses due to my damaged laptop for a while. I've tried as you suggested but it still can't display the result automatically. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I've figured out the solution,I'm simply remove the parseFloat and its do the trick. Thank you for your time

Comment: @Qilanasir good you found a solution. Could you add your solution with the code that you are now using (that works for you and solves your problem) as an answer and accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is my latest codes that work for me perfectly.
Form code:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <strong>Rate Lecture Per Hour (RM) :</strong>
   {!! Form::number('lecturePerHour', null, array('placeholder' => 'Rate Lecture Per Hour (RM)','class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'lecturePerHour', 'onchange' => 'calc()')) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <strong>Rate Tutorial Per Hour (RM) :</strong>
   {!! Form::number('tutorialPerHour', null, array('placeholder' => 'Rate Tutorial Per Hour (RM)','class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'tutorialPerHour', 'onchange' => 'calc()')) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <strong>Total Working Hour per Month (Lecture) :</strong>
   {!! Form::number('lectureWorkTime', null, array('placeholder' => 'Total Working Hour (Lecture)','class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'lectureWorkTime', 'onchange' => 'calc()')) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <strong>Total Working Hour per Month (Tutorial) :</strong>
   {!! Form::number('tutorialWorkTime', null, array('placeholder' => 'Total Working Hour (Tutorial)','class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'tutorialWorkTime', 'onchange' => 'calc()')) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <strong>Total Salary Per Month :</strong>
   {!! Form::text('totalSalary', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'totalSalary')) !!}
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function calc()
    {
      var value1 = document.getElementById('lecturePerHour').value;
      var value2 = document.getElementById('tutorialPerHour').value;
      var value3 = document.getElementById('lectureWorkTime').value;
      var value4 = document.getElementById('tutorialWorkTime').value;

      var result = (value1*value3)+(value2*value4);
      document.getElementById('totalSalary').value = "" +result;
    }
    </script>
```

Thanks guys replied my question before, very much appreciated.